# Angular two-way binding and mapping in UI

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I have a dummy question... (complete noobie on frontend side)

I am building a small CRUD project with Angular 4 and TypeScript where I make calls to an API in order to get and update phone numbers based on an id.

The phone number which I get from the service is pretty standard and divided in 3 parts:

1. country code
2. predial
3. actual number

But in the UI, I have actually two input fields - one for country code and predial together and a second one for the actual number. To visualize this, if the phone number I get from user is `+445551234567` when I am editing it, I have two input fields with `+44555` and `1234567`

In other words, I have to map the country code + predial together in the UI in my edit page and also when I make the update call back to the API, I need to be able to map it again to 3 variables.

In ideal world, I would map this in my service, but that's unfortunately not possible due to other restrictions.

So I have these models/interfaces:

```
export interface Contacts {
    email: string;
    phoneNumber: PhoneNumber;
    faxNumber: PhoneNumber;
}

export interface PhoneNumber {
    countryCode: string;
    predial: string;
    number: string;
}
```

And then in my Input component I have a form:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
     phoneCountryCodeAndPredial: new ValidatableFormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
     phoneNumber: new ValidatableFormControl(null, [Validators.required]),

     faxCountryCodeAndPredial: new ValidatableFormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
     faxNumber: new ValidatableFormControl(null, [Validators.required]),

     email: new ValidatableFormControl(null, [Validators.pattern(/\S+@\S+\.\S+/)])
});
```

And in the html just the phone number for brevity:

```
<div class="form-group-line">
   <input [formControl]="form.controls['phoneCountryCodeAndPredial']" name="countryCodeAndPredial"
   class="required"
   placeholder="Predial"
   [(ngModel)]=contacts.phoneNumber.countryCode/> 

   <input [formControl]="form.controls['phoneNumber']" name="phoneNumber"
   class="required"
   placeholder="Phone Number"
   [(ngModel)]="contacts.phoneNumber.number"/>
</div>
```

So I want two-way-data binding, that's why I am using the `[(ngModel)] banana in the box`, but how do I use two-way-data binding + mapping in the ngModel?

I cannot make a function that combines the country code and predial together and pass the value to the ngModel.

So how do I do this mapping in the UI? What is a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split up the `ngModel` binding:

```html
<text-input [formControl]="form.controls['phoneCountryCodeAndPredial']" 
  name="countryCodeAndPredial"
  class="required"
  placeholder="Predial"
  [ngModel]="contacts.phoneNumber.countryCode + contacts.phoneNumber.predial"
  (ngModelChange)="Utils.setCombinedNumber(contacts.phoneNumber, $event)"
>
```

And then set the correct fields on model change:

```ts
setCombinedNumber(phoneNumber: PhoneNumber, combined: string) {
  // your actual splitting code here
  let pattern = new RegExp(/^(\+\d{2})(\d+)$/);
  if (pattern.test(combined)) {
    let match = pattern.exec(combined);
    phoneNumber.countryCode = match[1];
    phoneNumber.predial = match[2];
  }
  else {
    // do some error handling here? maybe show a toast?
  }
}
```

Comment: Am I actually allowed to do such operations? (`contacts.phoneNumber.countryCode + contacts.phoneNumber.predial`). That looks fishy :) but I will try it! Thanks

Comment: Totally, you're just binding whatever value is between the quotation marks :)

Comment: I tried it, but when I do so, and I go to the edit page, the "Predial" input field just explodes :D i.e. I get something like: `+44+44+44+44+44+44+44+44+44+44+44+44+44+44+44+44555` :D instead of just `+44555`

Comment: Yeah, you probably want to write your own splitting code :D

Comment: Well, I though so, but when i remove `(ngModelChange)="setCombinedNumber(contacts.phoneNumber, $event)"` from the html, it's still happening. I guess the `<text-input>` just makes a lot of 'events' and with + operator it is appending it everytime by `[ngModel]="contacts.phoneNumber.countryCode + contacts.phoneNumber.predial"`

Comment: I just tried it out - no funny business in this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tW5Jj4pZpdREMGDsUwOx

Comment: Thanks for the help!